# Ruby: Need to install git to install RVM, and having trouble installing git on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, git, ubuntu, rubygems

I am new to Ruby and git so please stop me if it seems I am headed in the wrong direction :)

What I was trying to do was install RVM so I can more freely manage my gems.  I was doing that according to this tutorial: https://rvm.io

It says there that "To install and/or update the latest code from the github repository ( requires git"

So I started to install git (oh what fun...) and was following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git

and there the instructions say that I need to do this:

```
sudo -H -u gitosis gitosis-init < initialKeyFileName
where initialKeyFileName name is the name of a copy of the public key from your local machine which is on the server (i.e. the file ending in .pub)
```

So my questions is how do I find this .pub file?  Is it on my local computer somewhere or do I need to contact the sys admin?  Or is it the ,pub from a repository where I need to download from, which would be a Ruby repo since I was trying to install rails originally.

Seems a bit convoluted, doesn't it? :) Is there a better way to do all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats a terrible tutorial! There is no need to install the `gitosis` package. Uninstall it and just don't bother with that line and you should be fine. Similarly, you should not install `apache` or the like. Stick with `git-core` and maybe `gitk` if you want a UI later down the road for `git`-stuff. (Not quite sure of the ubuntu package names, as I don't use it)

You can also just download the install file from github, but `git` is so awesome I wouldn't recommend that.

If you want the latest version of it, you can always do a source install. Just make sure you set some stuff in `config.mak` to disable features you can find in the Makefile. You basically want to disable everything except OpenSSL. You will need the headers for OpenSSL and zlib.

To uninstall `gitosis`: `sudo apt-get purge gitosis`

Comment: I am also kind of new to Ubuntu, so what would be the best way to uninstall it?  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Genadinik I have edited the command into the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

While not solving your exact problem, the following sets up RVM and a few other libs that you will very likely need down the road using Ruby/Rails:

```
sudo apt-get -q -y install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16 
sudo apt-get -q -y install clang #(for rvm...otherwise rvm gives error on rvm install)
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Comment: Surely `rvm` can be configured to use `gcc` instead of `clang`? (Never used `rvm`)

Comment: Not sure; I didn't bother with getting into the details, just wanted to get up and running and installing clang fixes things nicely.

Comment: I will trust you that those are not viruses ;)

Comment: I already accepted @mathepic's answer, so I went through some of your question and upvoted them because your answer here really helped me out. :) Thanks!

Comment: No they're not viruses.. check out each lib !

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I'd expect that this ought to install git to the satisfaction of rvm:

```
sudo apt-get -y install git-core
```

Comment: Oh yeah this went through just fine! Thanks!